# how to update different table with radio button in phpmysql

Tags: php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test radio button</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="radio" name="row1"/>row1
        <input type="radio" name="row2"/>row2
        <input type="radio" name="row3"/>row3
        <input type="submit" value="update"/>
      </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I have a table called `table_test`. In this table there is a column named as 
`row1, row2 and row3`.

I want to update value of each column in radio button at a time. I need to update one column when I submit the form.

I have searched so many times google but I can't find the solution. Please show me how I can implement this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the radio button has to be the same. You use a 'value' attribute to identify the value on the server.

```
<input type="radio" value="row1" name="myRadio"/>row1
<input type="radio" value="row2" name="myRadio"/>row2
<input type="radio" value="row3" name="myRadio"/>row3
```

Now, you can get the value in PHP:

```
echo $_POST['myRadio'];
```

To use this value in a query, you could do this:

```
mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO myTable SET %s = 'myValue'", $_POST['myRadio']));
```

Be warned! Use something like PDO if you don't want your server to get hacked.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the above code will insert to  the same column corresponding to their value but i need to insert to a values in different column in table called "my table" just like voting when i click radiobutton 1 it will update value of that column.

Comment: @Gezachew This code does insert in different columns, depending on the radio button value. You will have a table with three columns. One of them will have the value "myValue" for each record.